# SQL Update Most Recent Date

Tags: sql, mysql

I have a table that stores member info.
The column 'added' stores the date they joined.

[View Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3jMQ2.jpg)

I want to get the most recent dates in the added column and update them to a specific date. Sometimes it is a single record, sometimes multiple.

The problem is using UPDATE and SELECT for the same table? Commonly this seems to be done more across two tables. I only have one.

This is what I've tried:

```
UPDATE `test`
SET `added` = `2023-08-24`
WHERE `added` =
(
SELECT * FROM `test` WHERE `added` = (select max(`added`) FROM `test`);
)
```

The SELECT command works when ran on the table so I know the data is being retrieved correctly. It's the combination of SELECT and UPDATE that I don't think works?

I will be executing the code from a PHP file.

**UPDATE**: Stack Overflow won't let me answer my own question

The solution seemed to be adding a subquery.
Found from [Infobird](https://www.inforbiro.com/blog/mysql-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause) blog.

```
UPDATE `test` SET `added` = '2023-08-24'
WHERE `added` IN (
  SELECT * from (
    SELECT MAX(`added`) FROM `test`
  ) as t
);
```

Seems to work correctly for me.

Comment: Which dbms are you using? (All the answers are product specific - for the same dbms as you're using?)

Comment: MySQL, the update I added to the OP worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

This is a way to do it using `inner join` :

```
update test t
inner join (
  select MAX(added) as max_added 
  FROM test
) as s on s.max_added = t.added
set t.added = '2023-08-24'
```

Comment: The update to my OP and this both seem to work. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a subquery to select the maximum date and then updating the rows with that date.

```
UPDATE `test`
SET `added` = '2023-08-24'
WHERE `added` = (SELECT MAX(`added`) FROM `test`);
```

However, this query will update all rows with the most recent date to the specified date. If you only want to update a specific number of rows, you could use this query instead:

```
UPDATE `test`
SET `added` = '2023-08-24'
WHERE `added` IN (SELECT `added` FROM `test` ORDER BY `added` DESC LIMIT 5);
```

Change the '**5**' to a integer of your preference.

Since you mentioned that you will be executing this code from a PHP file, make sure to use proper error handling and SQL injection prevention techniques in your PHP code.

Comment: Your first solution is the exact logic I want. 
When I run "Simulate query" with that it returns the correct results. However, when I try to execute I receive:  "#1093 - You can't specify target table 'test' for update in FROM clause"